# Bypassing Chrome's CORB Feature

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, cross-origin-read-blocking

I'm trying to load some external JavaScript, but Chrome isn't having it.
To be clear, I'm using a bookmarklet to create a new script element, change the src attribute to my source code, and then append it to the header.
Here's the code:

```js
javascript:var script=document.createElement("script");script.src="URL";document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Unfortunately, Chrome's Cross-Origin Read Blocking algorithm is preventing me from injecting the source into the header. I believe that this is due to the fact that said source document is simply plain text, and not an acceptable JavaScript file.
Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Works fine here. If the content of the URL being pointed to is `console.log('foo')`, I see `foo` being printed

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yeah. Sorry about that, but the problem was that the site I'm trying to do this on has Chrome's CORB enabled by default. I've rewritten the question accordingly. Again, I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: CORB errors mean that your URL doesn’t point to JS. You got your URL wrong.

Comment: @Quentin I'm pretty sure that CORB is an algorithm that's supposed to block "dubious" external scripts. All you have to do is add a MIME tag, and presto, scripts can't just bring in foreign sources. Here's my [evidence](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers).  Also, I assure you that my URL is fine.

Comment: @Larnyx — It does block dubious external scripts … by disallowing them when they don’t claim to be `text/javascript` and 99% of the time the error is triggered because someone tries to load an HTML document as a script because they typed the wrong URL in rather than because the script is dubious.

Comment: “ Unfortunately, my admin has restricted access to the site.” — If you mean your admin has restricted access to the site you are hosting your JS on then that isn’t a programming problem.

Comment: “ I believe that this is due to the fact that said source document is simply plain text, and not an acceptable JavaScript file.
Is there any workaround for this?” — Make it a JavaScript file! (Educated guess: You are trying to use Github as a webhosting service instead of a git repository hosting service. Don’t. Get a web hosting service. )

Comment: @Quentin I was referring to websiteasteroids.com, which is a project that uses a bookmarklet to inject external scripts. It was an example. If I had access to the site, and if the problem was based on the syntax of my code, then this would be easier for me to resolve. Regarding the second portion, you're correct. The URL is a raw GitHub file containing some JavaScript. I'll upload my code to some hoster instead, and get back to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many websites that because of CSP (Content Secrutiy Policy) not let you load scripts from other URLS. You should check the CSP headers of the website you trying to inject scripts into.

More info on CSP:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

### UPDATE

I see that your edit your question (after my initial answer) and now your asking specific about CORB issue. In that case you have to ensure that your script returing the correct `content-type` header. If you script doens't return `text/javascript` chrome will not execute it.

How do you serve the JavaScript file? if you will give more details we can try to help.

Usually servers are giving the correct header to JS files. There are some exception. For e.g. when user upload JS file to GitHub, GitHub will serve it without the content type header. This is because they don't want that a webmaster that trust only GitHub will have a risk that a user will execute user uploaded script (to GitHub) on his website.

More info:

- https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers

Comment: If there was a CSP issue, there would be a warning in the console, right?

Comment: Unless you're filtering that issue. Chrome sometimes moves error to others tabs in the console, and also there is an option to filter issue. So I'm not sure what happend in your case.

Comment: In addition to each website's CSP, if you're viewing your page from a `file://` context rather than being delivered from a web server, browsers enforce additional security restrictions. Some browsers more than others.

Comment: CORB has nothing to do with CSPs. This won’t help.

Comment: @AminadavGlickshtein Yeah, I'm using Chrome, and they have this CORB algorithm, which I'm fairly certain is the same thing.

Comment: @Larnyx — No. CORB and CSP are completely different. CORB is default browser behaviour designed to stop data formats which aren’t suitable for the place they are being loaded (such as an HTML document in a script element) from having side effects. CSP is a means for a site to explicitly restrict which resources can be loaded into it.

Comment: @Quentin I see. My apologies.

Comment: my answer was BEFORE the last edit of the author. Now I'm updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I've used is to put your script/gist into a Github repository and publish it as a static website using [Pages](https://pages.github.com/).  Github should server the JS file with the correct headers.